# perl calling another perl script with options/switches

Tags: perl

I have a master Perl script that needs to call another Perl script with options. I read many threads regarding arguments but I need both, arguments and options. Below is my sample code:

```
sub run_script_a{
   my $script_path = "/home/sample/script.pl"
   my @ARGS = "input.txt";

   ##I need to capture the result of the script run and fail if something went wrong
   system($^X, $tool_path, @ARGS);
}
```

I tried the following:

```
my @ARGS = "input.txt -o output.txt";
```

It didn't work, gave me this error:

```
Cannot open input.txt -o output.txt for read: No such file or directory
```

How do I make it work? The second script runs as:

```
sample.pl input.txt -o output.txt
```

I am not good at coding bash scripts so I am using Perl.

Comment: I tried this as well:   my @ARGS = ("input.txt", "-o ", "output.txt");. The error I get is: "Unknown option: o" The "-" is getting ignored even if I send "--o"

Comment: Remove the trailing space in "-o ". If you use a list as the arguments for `system`, it will not pass thru a shell, meaning extra spaces will not be ignored.

Comment: Removing the trailing space fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
my $tool_path = "/home/sample/script.pl"
my @args = "input.txt -o output.txt";
system($tool_path, @args);
```

is equivalent to the shell command

```
/home/sample/script.pl "input.txt -o output.txt"
```

You want

```
my $tool_path = "/home/sample/script.pl"
my @args = ( "input.txt", "-o", "output.txt" );
system($tool_path, @args);
```

Actually, if you want to capture the output, there's no need to involve a file. You want

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $tool_path = "/home/sample/script.pl"
my @args = "input.txt";
my $output = capturex($tool_path, @args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to run script with arguments and capture output (perldoc -f qx).

```
perl -E'say `echo 4 | $^X -p ./script.pl`'
```

Content of script.pl:

```
$_**=3
```